# Spring data jpa commit in normal java application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When using spring and spring data jpa in a normal java application how will jpa know when to commit the data to the database?

I ask this because repository.save() doesn't commit.

Should i manually commit or can spring handle this for me?

My application context xml:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="...">
    </context:component-scan>

<jpa:repositories base-package="..." entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"  />



<bean id="emf" class="...spring.MyEMF"></bean>

<!-- Add Transaction support -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>

<!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I manually init my context with:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/data.xml")
```

Comment: Try using repository.saveAndFlush()

Answer (score 0):

No spring can handle transaction for you just before your method repository.save() add @Transactional

```
@Transactional
public void save(){
   //do something
}
```

and in your configuration class make sure that spring transaction handling is enabled

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
class myConfig{

}
```

Comment: Hmm, i seem i was wrong, save() does commit. It seems that spring data jpa crud methods like save is @transactional by default. I've enabled logger org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager to see the details. I will need to do a bit research. Will come back soon.